Is it possible to take derivatives in R?
I am dealing with the following mathematical model:

Using R, I am interested in performing symbolic differentiation to find out the mathematical formulas for the first and second derivatives of this likelihood function with respect to beta and theta.
Doing some research, I found out about the Deriv package in R. I tried to code this myself.
First, for the Beta's:
library(Deriv)

LogL <- expression(
    -0.5 * (log(det(V)) + t(y - X %*% beta) %*% solve(V) %*% (y - X %*% beta))
)

dLogL_dbeta <- Deriv(LogL, "beta")
d2LogL_dbeta2 <- Deriv(dLogL_dbeta, "beta")

The theta's were more difficult - I first I had to define a matrix template and then do this:
V <- expression(matrix(
  c(theta[1] + theta[2], rep(theta[1], n-1),
    rep(theta[1], n-1), diag(rep(theta[1] + theta[2], n-1))),
  nrow = n, ncol = n
))

LogL_theta <- substitute(LogL, list(V = V))

dLogL_dtheta <- Deriv(LogL_theta, "theta")
d2LogL_dtheta2 <- Deriv(dLogL_dtheta, "theta")

But both of these are coming out as 0, and I know this is not correct.
Can someone please show me how to do this correctly?

May be this could help : calculus

@MrSmithGoesToWashington : thank you! I will check this out! have you ever used this package before?

Are you interested in finding the derivative or interested in optimizing it? If interested in finding the derivative, consider using mathematica or matlab. If interested in numerical derivative, use approximations

@Onyambu: thank you for your kind reply, I really appreciate it. I am interested in both, which do you think is easier in R?

In R, you could estimate the parameters directly using the optim function. This will do numerical differentiation for you

Could you please post an answer if you have time? Thank you so much

Look at the merDeriv package.  The associated article at DOI:10.18637/jss.v087.c01
has the formulas for the gradient and Hessian of the mixed model likelihood.  Also the lmeInfo package. There is an interactive web page at https://www.matrixcalculus.org which will perform matrix differentiation.  The likelihood in its notation in terms of b and V would be: -0.5 * (log(det(V)) +(y-X*b)'*inv(V)*(y-X*b))  or in terms of b, theta1 and theta2 -0.5 * (log(det(theta1*I+theta2*matrix(1))) +(y-X*b)'*inv(theta1*I+theta2*matrix(1))*(y-X*b))  For optimization see the CVXR pkgfor convex optimization.

Also lme4 does mixed models, the regress package considers the case where the variance is a linear combination of variance matrices and the Mixed Model Task View https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MixedModels.html lists many packages of which some may be of interest.

@G. Grothendieck : thank you for your reply and suggesting the merDeriv package. If you have time, I would be very grateful and deeply appreciative to see an example as to how I can use the merDeriv package for this problem. Thank you so much

The point is not so much the package itself but the DOI link to its article which shows the formulas.  Those together with matrixcalculus.org to handle variations and straight forward translation to R should get you what you need.

There is no data for the problem, so cannot really optimize the likelihood. Note that the model contains Z and U and these are not given anywhere
